# Exposing SQL fired when LINQ executes

Tags: sql, linq, conditional-statements, where-clause

Morning all.

Just a quick one for you - where can I find the SQL that is executed when a LINQ statement fires?

I have the following code that works a treat,

```
 var r = (from p in getproductweightsbuyer.tblWeights
                     where p.MemberId == memberid &&
                              p.LocationId == locationid
                     select p);

            if (buyer != "Not Specified")
                r = r.Where(p => p.UnitUserField1 == buyer);

            if (subcategory != "Not Specified")
                r = r.Where(p => p.UnitUserField2 == subcategory);
```

I'm just not sure of the SQL that is firing in the conditional where clause.

Comment: LINQ to SQL? Entity framework? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you debug your code you can put a breakpoint and analyze the value of `r`, which will have the actual SQL code in it.

Comment: Thanks Stefan - I couldn't remember at which point the SQL would be exposed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the database context at hand you could try:

```
context.GetCommand(query).CommandText
```

Comment: Nice - I did not know about this. Thanks Thorsten.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the above options, you can also run up SQL profiler and see the actual SQL sent down the wire to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you use LINQ to SQL you can set the `DataContext.Log` property. This will log the SQL when you execute the query:

```
getproductweightsbuyer.Log = Console.Out;

var r = (from p in getproductweightsbuyer.tblWeights
                    where p.MemberId == memberid &&
                             p.LocationId == locationid
                    select p);

           if (buyer != "Not Specified")
               r = r.Where(p => p.UnitUserField1 == buyer);

           if (subcategory != "Not Specified")
               r = r.Where(p => p.UnitUserField2 == subcategory);

foreach (var row in r)
  ...
```